# How can I set up a battery full notication on Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, battery, notification, source-code

Is there any software which can alert me when battery is 100 % ? I do not want to keep charging further causing battery damage. I use 20.04 LTS.

Comment: " I do not want to keep charging further causing battery damage. " That is NOT how batteries in a notebook work.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that it causes battery damage?

Comment: It makes some sense to warn when e.g. 80% is reached, then stop charging, obviously if you do not need the full capacity for while on the road. Not fully loading nor discharging is less strainful for a battery and makes it last longer.